# How to acces the 'ofMessageArchive' table from the openfire server in android application?

Tags: android, xmpp, openfire, smack

I have installed Monitoring plugin enabled the archive setting.

Now I can access the ofMessageArchive table in server side(openfire) and can able to see the chat history in table, I need to access the table in my application(client).

Now, How to get the chat history in my application from table ofMessageArchive ?

Any help would be much appreciated.Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Openfire's Monitoring Plugin provides [XEP-0136](https://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0136.html) and [XEP-0313](https://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0313.html) support. 
Now you need to check the support of these extensions in Smack library and as per Smack Jira, it provides [XEP-0313 support](https://issues.igniterealtime.org/browse/SMACK-625). So you need to understand the supported XEP and query the server using the provided IQ queries and you will be able to get required chat messages.

As per standard, this is the way to query server for chat history.